# Replacing substring within curly braces with an ordered index by using Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The following is an example of my excel data:

```js
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| A                                                         | B                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Copyright {year} Company. All rights,reserved.            | Copyright {0} ABB. All rights,reserved. |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| The {startDate} and {endDate} must be within {objectType} | The {0} and {1} must be within {2}      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Unit of measure conversion                                | Unit of measure conversion              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Is there any Excel formula solution to replace any substring within curly braces in column A to ordered index within curly braces in column B?

I am thinking to use SUBSTITUTE. But, I got stuck on how to get substring within curly braces and to substitute it with an ordered index. Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Does {year} {year} in the same line need to get replaced with {0} {0} or {0} {1}?

Comment: You would need to "array"  the text to multiple parts, which would be hard to do. But then you also would need to put everything together again which is something excel don't want by formula. I suggest an UDF for this tast as there is no build-in formula in excel which can do something like that :(

Comment: not sure if it works in Excel, but in Google Sheets =REGEXREPLACE(A2, "\{([A-Za-z]+)\}", "{}") comes really close (just missing the numbers).

Comment: @JeremyKahan Thanks for asking and giving regex solution. I'd expect an ordered number per line per key. So that, "The {year} and {year}" should be transformed to "The {0} and {0}". :)

Comment: @DirkReichel Yaps, that would be a good alternative if nothing can be done by using standard Excel formula. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: @gusdewa Is my answer not working?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

EDIT: In case you did not know it.
The code below is a UDF, and needs to be inserted in the VBA editor ALT + F11.
Click insert -> module and copy paste the code. 
Close VBA editor.
Remember to save the file as  a macroactivated file (xlsm) when you save it.

```
Function Regex(Cell1, Cell2)
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim RE2 As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set RE2 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RE.Pattern = "(\{.*?\})"
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True

    RE2.Pattern = "\{(.*?)\}"
    RE2.Global = True
    RE2.IgnoreCase = True
    A = Cell1.Address
    B = Cell2.Address
    Set Matches = RE.Execute(Range(A).Value)
    Set Matches2 = RE2.Execute(Range(B).Value)

    If Matches.Count <> 0 And Matches2.Count <> 0 And Matches.Count = Matches2.Count Then
        For myMatchCt = 0 To Matches.Count - 1
            For subMtCt = 0 To Matches.Item(subMtCt).SubMatches.Count - 1
                If Regex = "" Then
                    Regex = Replace(Range(A).Value, Matches.Item(myMatchCt).SubMatches.Item(subMtCt), Matches2.Item(myMatchCt).SubMatches.Item(subMtCt))
                Else
                    Regex = Replace(Regex, Matches.Item(myMatchCt).SubMatches.Item(subMtCt), Matches2.Item(myMatchCt).SubMatches.Item(subMtCt))
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Else
        Regex = Range(A).Value
    End If

End Function
```

Usage: `=Regex(Source, replace)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Andreas. It is working only if B is defined. My question is to generate B, which is not defined, from A, and not generating C. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: So where do you get the replace text from then? Lets say column A is the original text, in column B you want the complete text with curly braces replaced, but where do I get the replacement text to the curly braces?